# Python 3: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__' using urllib in terminal

Tags: python, urllib

My code is runnning perfectly in PyCharm, but I have error messages while trying to open it in terminal. What's wrong with my code, or where I made mistakes?

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
   html = response.read()
   print(html)
```

Output from terminal:

```
λ python Desktop\url1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop\url1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package
```

Comment: `import urllib.request` is valid ???

Comment: @VivekSable, yes for python3.

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to run a file using `python -m thing.py` instead of `python thing.py` 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You called a file `C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\urllib.py`, you need to rename it. You are importing from that not the actual module. rename `C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\urllib.py` and remove any `C:\Users\Przemek\Desktop\urllib.pyc`.

It is not the file you are running  but you have the file in the same directory so python checks the current directory first hence the error.

Comment: Yes, that's it, I had a file named urllib.py in same directory. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Przemek. no prob, happens pretty often

Answer (score 1):

You sare shadowing the standard library package `urllib` by naming your source file `urllib.py`. Rename it!

The fact this works at all in Pycharm is an amazing feat of engineering on the PyCharm developers!

You can also use absolute imports (`from __future__ import absolute_import`) here; but in this case I don't think it'll help since your startup source name shadows the very library/package you are trying to use!

Answer (score -1):

Also, this:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
```

Should be like this:

```
import urllib
with urllib.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
```

Comment: Not really, the OP is using python3.

Comment: My Bad, thought 2.7!!