# 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to communicate my pc with an arduino, but I get the error mentioned in the title, module objet has no attribute Serial.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Importamos la libreira de PySerial
import serial

# Abrimos el puerto del arduino a 9600
PuertoSerie = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
# Creamos un buble sin fin
while True:
  # leemos hasta que encontarmos el final de linea
  sArduino = PuertoSerie.readline()
  # Mostramos el valor leido y eliminamos el salto de linea del final
  print "Valor Arduino: " + sArduino.rstrip('\n')
```

The curios thing is the the  code used to work, but then I installed matplotlib and drawnow libraries, I believe that has caused the problem but I don't know how to fix it, because and need those libraries any way.

The other matter is that is I copy the code line to line into the terminal it works but of course I need I with the loop in a .py file.

Comment: what is the exact traceback? This more than likely applies to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261860/python-3-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-path-using-urll/30261879#30261879

Comment: What is the name of your script?

Comment: let me guess - your script is called serial.py? Then python takes __that__ instead of the serial module in the library. Rename it, and remove any lingering *.pyc-file.

Comment: Yeah it was that, I have read the post already, I misunderstood the post the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to not name the source file `serial.py` since in such case Python takes that instead of the actually desired `serial` module.

(Since the question was solved in the comments and no answer has been posted, inspired by a [relevant meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) I'm adding this answer to make the question complete. I'm not trying to get credit for [deets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84308/deets)' solution and I'm posting it as a *community wiki* answer.)